# How to open Bootstrap carousel image on a new page within the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have created an image gallery with bootstrap.All I want is,when some click on a particular image it should take them to a new page which will show the image on bootstrap carousel slider.

That means I want to make it dynamic with onclick event and pass the id via url from one to another so that we can see the same image on the slider when the page loads.

So if some can help me out how to implement it I will be really obliged.

Thanks

Comment: You need to fetch the id from url by server, then your server will catch it and show it at the slider. In which framework/language you backend is? or you can use cookies/localStorage to show the image.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply add an anchor tag then add image inside that anchor like this

```
<a href="http://destination or image url/"> 
  <img src="http://imageurl" alt="">
</a>
```